# Swift: Unowned references

Tags: ios, swift

The swift documentation says

> unowned references are defined using non-optional types.

But we can define an unowned variable as optional. It doesn't seem like a hard requirement for an unowned to be non-optional.

What is difference between weak optional & unowned optional..?

```
 class Person {

        let name: String
        var apartment: Apartment?

        init(name: String) {
            self.name = name
            print("\(name) is being initialized")
        }
        deinit {
            print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
        }
    }


    class Apartment {
        let unit: String
        init(unit: String) { self.unit = unit }
        unowned var tenant: Person?
        deinit { print("Apartment \(unit) is being deinitialized") }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither `weak` nor `unowned` increase the reference count of an object; That is they will not prevent an object from being released if there are no remaining strong references.

The main difference between `weak` and `unowned` is what happens when the referred-to object is released; a `weak` reference becomes `nil` while an `unowned` reference still holds a (now invalid) reference to the object, so your program will crash if you try and access it.

Using an optional for an weak reference is required, since it can become `nil`.  Using an optional for an unowned reference is syntactically possible, but the semantics aren't sensible.  From the Swift Programming language book:

> ...an unowned reference is used when the other instance has the same lifetime or a longer lifetime

Given this definition, there is no point at which the `unowned` property should be `nil`.  You can see this from your example; Clearly it is possible for an apartment to be without a tenant and a person who is currently a tenant can cease to exist; If you use `unowned` with an optional `tenant` you will be left with an invalid tenant reference.

Consider the difference between this and the credit-card example given in the book:

> The relationship between `Customer` and `CreditCard` is slightly different from the relationship between Apartment and Person seen in the weak reference example above. In this data model, a customer may or may not have a credit card, but a credit card will always be associated with a customer. A `CreditCard` instance never outlives the `Customer` that it refers to. To represent this, the `Customer` class has an optional card property, but the `CreditCard` class has an unowned (and non-optional) customer property.